# Is there a standard for toolbar icon dimensions based on DPI?

Tags: user-interface, mfc, toolbar, dpi

I have a 32 pixel toolbar:

[image: Toolbar]

Is there a known standard for using different pixel heights for the toolbar based on different DPI configurations? If so, can you please point in in the right direction of this resource?

The only thing I have located about this concept is [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/4879952/How-to-setup-toolbars-CMFCToolbar-for-small-and-la.aspx) and I quote the example pseudo code:

```
UINT smallToolbarID;
if ( DPI == smaller )
{
  smallToolbarID = 16x16;
  largeToolbarID = 32x32
}
else if ( DPI == medium )
{
  smallToolbarID = 20x20;
  largeToolbarID = 40x40
}
else if ( DPI == larger)
{
  smallToolbarID = 24x24;
  largeToolbarID = 48x48
}
```

In the above link the comment states:

> Now if I have to do this **"by the book"** I would need to generate toolbars with buttons 16x16, 20x20, 24x24, 32x32, 40x40 and 48x48.

I would appreciate guidance for statement.

Comment: DPI settings 100, 125, 150, 175, 200 correspond to 16, 20, 24, 28, 32 pixels for small icons. You can use one set of 32x32 icons, then load the icons with `LoadIconWithScaleDown`, this should show smooth icons in all DPI settings.

Comment: Pretty dated document, but have a look at [size requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/vis-icons#size-requirements).

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks. However I am not using ICO resources. This is a PNG resource for the toolbar loaded like this: m_ToolBar.LoadToolBarEx(IDR_TOOLBAR, info, FALSE);  The resource ID of the image is passed in the info parameter. So not sure if I can use the method you referred to?

Comment: You could dump your PNG's into an ICO file (see [The evolution of the ICO file format, part 4: PNG images](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101022-00/?p=12473)). I don't know whether [LoadIconWithScaleDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-loadiconwithscaledown) supports PNG icons.

Comment: Was there ever a sample of how to do this properly?   The MFC toolbar exists as a resource, do you have to create several, or is there a way to just create a generic one and change the icons/graphic (say using a single ico file with different sizes)?